# Is it possible to query Kusto cluster to setup a monitoring alert on Application Insights?

Tags: azure-application-insights, azure-data-explorer, azure-monitoring

I want to create an alert rule on Application insight based on the results of a query on kusto table.
Essentially, would want to run a query against kusto table on Application Insights

Comment: Yes this is possible: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/alerts/alerts-log#create-a-log-alert-rule-with-the-azure-portal

Comment: @PeterBons but it doesn't let me use "adx" in setting up log alerts. It throws below error ```   "innererror": {
      "code": "QueryValidationError",
      "message": "The 'adx' pattern cannot be used with the current authentication scheme"```

Comment: @Swasti could you pls add your kusto query in the question? That may help to troubleshot.

Comment: How are setting up the alert, you are not doing it using the portal are you?

Comment: I can use the kusto c luster using adx from Application Insights Logs worksapce but not using Azure monitor testing. I just found that on the Microsoft document. I will find an alternate tool to implement the monitoring alert. Thank you

Comment: If the answer below answers your question, please accept it by clicking the "V" icon. If you're still missing info, please add a comment elaborating what info you need. Thanks.

Comment: @Swasti I know this is old, but do you recall what alternative you came up with?

Answer (score 0):

As [@Peter said](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/alerts/alerts-log#log-alert-for-log-analytics-and-application-insights) in the comment, application insights provides the feature to alert besides the kusto query result, but pls note here, Log Alerts can be based on two types of Measures: Number of results and Metric measurement, that means you can't edit the alert rules freely. If you have trouble on the kql query, pls add more details on your requirement here, many thanks for your reply.

[image]